# Do not cast shadows when transparent in unity

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph, unity-webgl

I am developing a game for WebGL and I have a shader that makes parts of an object in specific ranges of coordinates transparent, like so:

[image: shader]

This shader makes all parts of an object with an absolute Y-coordinate of more than 1.7 transparent. But these parts still cast a shadow:

[image: gif of shadow being cast]

How do I stop them from casting a shadow?

Answer (score -1):

This may be a bit sideways – there may well be a [shader keyword](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/shader-keywords.html) you can define that does the same — but what about simply waiting for the object to complete it's animation/movement then setting Cast Shadows -> Off on the Mesh Renderer?

The main issue I see is, from a shader perspective, I believe your shadows will be all or nothing. And maybe you can drive shadow casting from the shader, toggling it on and off at the appropriate time, but there may be a simpler solution here.